# If/else re-evaluate (integer only solutions)

Tags: infinite-loop

I am trying to get *Mathematica* to do an if/else loop. I can get as far as the if, but I would like it to re-evaluate until only integer solutions are found. Here is what I have:

```
If[sols = 
Flatten[{x, y} /. 
Solve[{(q1 = 
    RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] y + 
      RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] x == 
     RandomChoice[Join[Range[-10, -1], Range[1, 10]]]),
  (q2 = 
    RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] y + 
      RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] x == 
     RandomChoice[Join[Range[-10, -1], Range[1, 10]]])}, {x, y}]];
IntegerQ[sols[[1]]] && IntegerQ[ sols[[2]]], {q1, 
q2}, "Not Integers"]
```

## Update

After playing with rasher's first code:

```
TraditionalForm[Column[Table[n = While[(sols = Flatten[{x, y} /.
     (sol = 
       Solve[{(q1 = 
           RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] y + 
             RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] x == 
            RandomChoice[
             Join[Range[-10, -1], Range[1, 10]]]), (q2 = 
           RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] y + 
             RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] x == 
            RandomChoice[
             Join[Range[-10, -1], Range[1, 10]]])}, {x, y}])]; 
  Not[IntegerQ[sols[[1]]] && IntegerQ[sols[[2]]]])];
  Grid[{{Column[{q1, q2}],
  Flatten[sol]}}, ItemSize -> 10, 
  Alignment -> {{Left, Left}}], {n, 1, 10}]]]
```

Comment: You try to get *Mathematica* to do an if/else loop? There aren't many things I haven't seen so far as computer scientist, but an *if/else loop* is one of the things that I never saw :-)

Comment: Not a good idea then? ;)

Comment: It was a joke. There is no if/else **loop**. if/else is a *conditional expression*. `While`,`For`,`Do` are loops.

Comment: @halirutan: `If[# > 10, #, #0[# + 1]] &[2]` ;-}

Comment: OK - I'm not a computer scientist, (you might have guessed ;))

Comment: @martin Let's assume someone can give you your integer solutions in a better/faster approach. Can you maybe add information what exactly you want. Do you really need only the first solution which is hit at random or do you need many different solutions?

Comment: @rasher You've got a D- in _recursion_ :)

Comment: @belisarius: Lol, it *is* a loop... )

Comment: @halirutan - yes, I would like to generate a worksheet - can do it as a table using rasher's code, but still working on keeping `TraditionalForm`

Comment: @rasher Oh well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cobbling your code, exits when integer solution found:

```
While[(sols = 
   Flatten[{x, y} /. 
     Solve[{(q1 = 
         RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] y + 
           RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] x == 
          RandomChoice[Join[Range[-10, -1], Range[1, 10]]]), (q2 = 
         RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] y + 
           RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]] x == 
          RandomChoice[Join[Range[-10, -1], Range[1, 10]]])}, {x, 
       y}]]; Not[IntegerQ[sols[[1]]] && IntegerQ[sols[[2]]]])]

{sols, q1, q2}

(* {{16, -9}, -2 x - 3 y == -5, 3 x + 5 y == 3} *)
```

A bit cleaner way:

```
c1 := RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]];
c2 := RandomChoice[Join[Range[-10, -1], Range[1, 10]]];

While[(sol = 
    Flatten[{x, y} /. 
      Solve[{q1 = c1 y + c1 x == c2, q2 = c1 y + c1 x == c2}, {x, y}, 
       Integers]]) == {x, y}]
{sol, q1, q2}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks rasher :)

Comment: @martin: take a look at update, a bit cleaner way that will be easier to change parameters.

Comment: @ rasher, great - looks much more efficient :) - I will have a play

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are interested in all 649024 solutions, here is the code that goes through every possible combination of your values for the factors (takes about 20s here!)

```
all = With[{vars = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6}},
   With[{iters = 
      Transpose[{vars, 
        Join[Range[-#, -1], Range[1, #]] & /@ {5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 10}}],
     acceptableQ = 
      First[{x, y} /. 
        Solve[{a1 y + a2 x == a3, a4 y + a5 x == a6}, {x, y}]]
     },
    Quiet[
      Last@Last[
        Reap[Table[
            If[And @@ (IntegerQ /@ acceptableQ), 
             Sow[{acceptableQ, vars}]], ##] & @@ iters]]]
    ]
   ];
```

The output `all` is a very long list where each element is of the form `{{x,y},{a1,...,a6}}`. The `a`'s are your factors you usually choose randomly. Pretty printing some of the results shows that is seems to be correct:

```
showResult[{{x_, y_}, {a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_}}] := 
 HoldForm[{a1 y + a2 x == a3, a4 y + a5 x == a6}];

showResult /@ RandomChoice[all, 10] // Column
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And if you don't want to check this by hand, you could release the `HoldForm` and see that all equations are indeed true with integer values for `x` and `y`

```
ReleaseHold[%]
(* {True,True}
{True,True}
{True,True}
{True,True}
{True,True}
{True,True}
{True,True}
{True,True}
{True,True}
{True,True} *)
```

Comment: @ halirutan, Just wow :o

Comment: I will definitely look into this - as I have a problem with repeats with random integer. Might take me some time though ;)